# Do villages generate in biome subtypes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I'm doing minecraft modding, and I made a new dimension: The Cheese Dimension. I made it the desert biome except with cheese blocks replacing the stone (and sand and stuff). I was wandering through this new dimension when POOF, a village generates right in front of me.[image: Cheese Village]

Plus, all the villagers are glitched out, running around, bouncing up and down in an empty spot, and generally being crazy.

I can change the biome, but if, for instance, I change it to forest, trees generate everywhere. NO. So are there any biomes where *nothing* special generates? Grass is fine, but anything besides the base "filler" blocks is bad. Lava lakes are okay, but I'd prefer if those didn't generate earlier.

This question was triggered my minecraft modding, but not caused by it.

Comment: Maybe you could look into the superflat/customised world generation code. There are options to generate or not generate structures, so you could use similar code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of biomes that are available in Minecraft:

- Ice plains
- Ice Spikes
- Cold Taiga/Taiga/Mega Taiga
- River/Frozen River
- Beach/Cold Beach/Stone Beach
- Extreme Hills
- Plains
- Forest/Birch Forest
- Roofed Forest
- Swampland
- Jungle
- Mushroom Island
- The End/Nether
- Desert
- Savanna
- Mesa/Plateau

From these, we can start to remove any that spawn anything special:

> Villages generate naturally in plains, savanna, taiga, and desert biomes. In Bedrock Edition, villages may also generate in ice plains and cold taiga biomes.

Additionally, we can remove, the End/Nether (obviously). In the case of trees, we can also remove any forests (Birch, Roofed etc), Jungle, and Taiga biomes, the Swamp which also spawn Witch Huts, Mushroom Island and the Ice Spikes biomes.

That leaves:

- Ice Plains
- River
- Beach
- Extreme Hills
- Mesa/Plateau

For the most part, these biomes are fairly void of most things - apart from the occasional tree, or perhaps reed. The only downside is perhaps the weather - if it's ok to have snow in the cheese dimension then I think they'd do the job.

You can see a full list of all the biomes [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome).